# A problem of optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Determine the maximum of $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)=\displaystyle\prod_{i \ne j}|x_i-x_{j}|$ for $0\le x_1<x_2<x_3< \dots<x_n<1 $.

It seems that you can always translate $x_i$'s such that $x_n \to 1$.
At the same time one always maximizes the value of $f$ when stretching on the right $x_i$'s, ie when $x_1=0$
So we just need to consider $n-2$ values.
Using dumb calculations (derivatives...), we get that:

for $n=2$, $\max=1$

for $n=3$, $\max=\frac 1 4$

for $n=4$, $\max=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{125}$...

Is there a way to find it in general ?

Comment: Is this a correct summary of the question: Given $n-1$ positive numbers $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_{n-1}$  whose total $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_{n-1} = 1$, what is the maximum of their product?

Comment: If my summary is correct, we can use the fact that for positive numbers the Geometric Mean is always $\leq$ the Arithmetic Mean to show that for $n-1$ numbers (corresponding with $n$ $x_i$'s), the maximum product will be $\frac{1}{(n-1)^{n-1}}$. Also, in this case, the product should be corrected to read $\prod \lvert x_{i+1} - x_i\rvert$

Comment: ...or $\prod x_{i+1} - x_i$, since $x_{i+1} > x_i$, by definition.

Comment: Also, in your question you state $x_n < 1$ but then immediately below that you set $x_n = 1$. I assume the first should be $x_n \leq 1$ but my suggested edit was rejected.

Comment: @Ben actually it doesn't matter... if $1$ is excluded, the maximum value would be a limit case... So such modifications are useless

Comment: your summary seems wrong @Ben

Comment: I take you point, but technically in that case there would be no maximum, since for any $x_n$ we pick, we can always find a greater one. It's like asking, "what's the greatest number $< 2$? The answer isn't $2$. The answer is, "There isn't one."

Comment: Or as an intermediate step, is this a correct interpretation: Given $n-1$ intervals with lengths that add up to 1, what is the maximum value of the product of their lengths?

Comment: Do you seek an analytical solution to the problem? Otherwise, just reformulate it as a geometric program and solve.

Comment: Yes @bodil I seek an analytical solution.

Comment: One possible alternate method: set $x_1 = 0$ and $x_n = 1$ as you have done already. For an $x_i$ with $1 < i < n$, differentiate the product with respect to $x_i$. Show that this will zero and will indicate a local maximum for $x_i = \frac{x_{i+1} + x_{i-1}}{2}$. You can then show this corresponds with equally spaced $x$'s. Or something like that. Maybe?

Comment: For $n=3$ the maximum should be $\frac{1}{16}$, unless you actually mean $\prod_{i>j}\lvert x_i - x_j\rvert$. And it seems that only the constraint $0 \leq x_i < 1$ is required.

Comment: @bodil agreed. I was assuming the product was maybe written incorrectly. It seems like a much nastier problem if the product is as written.

Comment: Hm...I think maybe you can still use the arithmetic mean to find the max value, even using the product as written...

Comment: @Ben I don't know how to use AM GM inequality here... Could you explain ?

Comment: @Bastien Tourand: Not sure it will work and I fear the actual calculation is currently beyond me, but I can sketch out the general idea for a simpler case if you like.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I'm not convinced that there is a "nice" algebraic solution to this problem, but one can transform it into a convex program which can be solved efficiently. The objective is equal to $$f(x) = \prod_{i>j} (x_i-x_j)^2,$$ subject to the constraint $0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n < 1$.
Now, let $y_i = x_{i+1} - x_i, i=1,\ldots,n-1$, then $x_{i}-x_{j} = \sum_{k=j}^i y_k$ for $j > i$, and the optimization problem can equivalently be reformulated as:
$$
\begin{split}
\max_y &\left\{f(y)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\prod_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i}^jy_k\right\} \\
&s.t.\\
&\mathbf{1}^\top y=1,\\
&y\succ 0.
\end{split}
$$

One can solve this by solving the equivalent convex program
$$\begin{split}
\max_y & \left\{ g(y) =\sum_{j>i}\log\left(\sum_{k=i}^j y_k\right)\right\}\\
&s.t.\\
&\mathbf{1}^\top y=1,\\
&y\succ 0,
\end{split}
$$
where the solution to the original problem is recovered from $\exp(2g(y^*))$, with $y^*$ the maximizer of the above program. Maybe we can get close to a solution by examining the Lagrangian
$$
L(y,\lambda) = \sum_{j>i}\log\left(\sum_{k=i}^j y_k\right) + \lambda(1 - \mathbf{1}^\top y),
$$
and finding $y^*$ s.t. $\nabla_y L(y,\lambda) = 0$ with $y\succ 0$.

Hope this is helpful, I will try to do something more later.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Arithmetic Mean as an upper bound, using a simpler case**

Using $x_i$'s with
$$0\le x_1<x_2<x_3< \dots<x_n\leq1$$
let's look instead at the max value of a simpler product
$$g(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n) = \prod (x_{i+1} - x_i)$$
We can see that $g$ is the product of the lengths of the line segments formed between all the $x_i$'s:
$$\prod (x_{i+1} - x_i) = (x_n - x_{n-1})(x_{n-1} - x_{n-2})\dots(x_2 - x_1)$$
Furthermore, because $x_i < x_{i+1}$, we know each term is positive.

To simplify things, let's call each of these terms $a_i$ where

$$a_i = x_{i+1} - x_i$$

We want to know the max value of
$$a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}$$

For positive numbers we know that the Geometric Mean (GM) is less than or equal to the Arithmetic Mean (AM).

Looking at the line we can see that, as long as we keep $x_1 = 0$, $x_n = 1$, and obey the general other constraints, the sum of all the segment lengths will remain maxed out at $1$, regardless of our placement of the interior $x_i$'s.

$$AM = \frac{\sum a_i}{n-1} = \frac {1}{n-1}$$

Moving around the $x_i$'s (aka increasing and decreasing the interior segment lengths) *will* change the value of the product of all the $a_i$'s, and consequently will increase or decrease the value of the GM.

GM will reach its maximum value when it's equal to the AM.

This occurs when

$$GM = \sqrt[n-1]{\prod a_i} = \frac {1}{n-1}$$
$$\prod a_i = \frac {1}{(n-1)^{n-1}}$$

$$g_{\max} = \frac {1}{(n-1)^{n-1}}$$

You can see that this happens when the $x_i$'s are evenly spaced and the intervals all have length $\frac {1}{n-1}$.

**More complicated product**

I don't know if this approach might be helpful with the nastier product $\prod_{i \ne j}|x_i-x_{j}|$, but it might be worth looking into. If the sum of the lengths of all the intervals in this product is similarly constant regardless of moving around interior $x_i$'s, you might be able to do the same trick.

I'm sorry if this isn't helpful!

Comment: On second thought, probably not useful for the more difficult product. The GM only equals the AM when all the terms in the product are equal, which is clearly not the case for the more difficult product. Sorry to waste your time!